# Кнопка не растягивается на 2 строки

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Не могу понять по какой причине кнопка с ID totalButton, не расширяется на 2 строки, хотя `rowSpan="2"` указан.

Буду благодарен если кто-то укажет на мою ошибку.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/memory_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            tools:text="Memory Field"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/operation_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            tools:text="Operation Field"
            />

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnCount="4"
            android:rowCount="5">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/sumButton"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/differenceButton"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/multiplicationButton"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/divisionButton"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/button7"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/button8"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/button9"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/clearButton"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/button4"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/button5"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/button6"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/notYetDefinied"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/button1"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/button2"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/button3"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/totalButton"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/button0"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/commaButton"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:id="@+id/reverseButton"/>

        </GridLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле для кнопки `totalButton` доступна площадь двух клеток (по вертикали), но чтобы растянуть эту кнопку по всей доступной площади, необходимо добавить этой кнопке атрибут:

```
android:layout_gravity="fill"
```

Чтобы растянуть кнопку по высоте, нужно добавить атрибут:

```
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
```

В Вашем случае подойдет любой из этих атрибутов, но второй будет предпочтительнее.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.